# Grinder: TCPProxy splits tests into multiple pages

Tags: automated-tests, performance-testing, stress-testing, grinder

I have an issue when recording tests using the Grinder TCPProxy. When I record a test for a single page, it splits the resultant test script into multiple page sections.

It seems to treat very short delays between browser initiated HTTP requests (even as short as as a few milliseconds) as if I clicked on links to separate pages. I end up with a script which tests the main HTML page separately from CSS and JS files.

Is there a parameter I can set when recording which would tell the Grinder TCPProxy to wait more then a specified time before splitting tests into separate pages?

Answer (score 0):

I designed an alternative to the TCPProxy: I record tests by using Chrome's Dev Tools and then convert them into scripts which The Grinder can run.

**Blog post:** 
http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/09/28/website-performance-script-for-the-grinder-using-har2grinder/

**Tool:**
https://github.com/postrational/har2grinder/